# Windows applications not restoring on restart

Tags: windows-10, reboot

**Summary**
When I restart, applications that should reopen automatically afterwards do not do so.  I've checked all of the relevant steps that I can find, however none have any effect.  Basic information on this issue can be found in [this related answer](https://superuser.com/a/1445783/237182).

**System Details**
Windows 10 Enterprise, version 1903, build 18362.267.  This is a fresh install (not an upgrade) of Windows 10 on a desktop that used to run Windows 7.  It's not connected to an Active Directory.

**Problem Specifics**
When I restart, no applications reopen, although many should.  Examples include browsers (e.g. Chrome, Firefox, Edge) and Microsoft Office programs (e.g. Outlook).  As discussed in the comments below, the online documentation on this can be confusing since this feature in Windows has evolved over time, as have the applications that support it, but I am contrasting this problematic desktop with observed behavior on two other laptops, both of which received a clean Windows 10 Enterprise install.  On both of these laptops, applications reopen both when Windows performs an automatic update + restart and when I initiate the restart, [as they should](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/49963-use-sign-info-auto-finish-after-update-restart-windows-10-a.html).

In terms of problem diagnosis, I have run through a host of means of enabling/disabling this feature, however none have any effect on whether it occurs.

- I have verified that the requisite setting is enabled (see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027599/windows-10-automatically-finish-setting-up-pc-after-update-restart)).
- I have verified that the requisite registry key is set (see Option 2 [here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/49963-use-sign-info-auto-finish-after-update-restart-windows-10-a.html)).
- I have verified that the local computer policy is set to "Not configured" (see Option 3 in last link).

In all cases, toggling these has no effect on restart behavior, though the option in the Settings menu does disappear (as it should) when it is disabled by other methods.  Lastly, note that folders **do** reopen on restart of the misbehaving computer, which, as also noted in [the answer](https://superuser.com/a/1445783/237182) mentioned at the start of this post, is a separate option from application restoring.

**Down the Road**
For future readers, there is also some discussion in [forum pages](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/49963-use-sign-info-auto-finish-after-update-restart-windows-10-a-3.html) about further evolution of this feature in future releases (starting in build 18963) about modification to the behavior.  Although this is a later build than mine, out of an abundance of caution, I did try adding the registry key described [here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/138685-turn-off-automatically-restart-apps-after-sign-windows-10-a.html) (the setting doesn't appear in the Settings menu in my build, as it shouldn't), but this had no effect.

Comment: This feature actually only restarts certain types of applications.  What type of applications are not being restarted, WIN32 or UWP, applications?  This feature also requires.  Reading the description of the policy, even if it was not configured, this policy would only apply to Windows Update restarts.  Is the machine you described connected to an AD domain?

Comment: @Ramhound, note from my second link, "Starting with Windows 10 16251, the advanced Windows Update feature to use your sign-in info to automatically finish setting your device after an update has been extended to regular reboots and shutdowns. "

Comment: @harrymc, my question clearly indicates I've attempted the steps in the related question, to no success, and so this is not a duplicate.

Comment: @TTT - Your third link if it's specific to 18963+ would not apply to your current installation only the feature release expected in the first half of 2020.  So if you are asking if the reason that registry key does not work, that would be the reason, it does not apply to 1903

Comment: @harrymc - There is no reason this author should not improve this question, and make it clear the reason this question is not a duplicate, if anything reposting the same question would result it being a duplicate of this question.  **This question has already recieved 3 reopen votes by the way.**  I suspect it will be reopen by the end of the day.

Comment: @Ramhound: That's fine - I wanted to spare the poster the saga of waiting for enough reopen votes. But without improving the post he risks getting it closed again. If he improves it, I'll reopen it myself.

Comment: @harrymc I'm not sure what else I can add, but am open to recommendations.  I've make clear that I've attempted all options provided in the answer to the other question, to no avail.  The other question itself has almost zero details from the asker, so there's not really anything for me to compare to there.  I've toggled all the registry keys and settings I can find, but nothing has any effect.  It's worth noting that the duplicate question does not have an accepted answer, and from the comments, it's unclear if it was resolved.

Comment: You could list the applications involved and research the question of whether these applications are configured for relaunch after a reboot. Enabling restart involves making a specific Windows API call inside the application, as is explained in the answer on that post.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with that, though I've already said it's an issue for all applications, including ones that restart on other Win10 systems.  Regardless, I've updated the post with examples.