# Is there a difference between shutting down via Alt+F4 -> Shut down and Start menu -> Shut down?

Tags: windows, windows-10, multi-boot

I am noticing a weird issue: if I shut down using "Start menu -> Shut down", when I start Windows again it takes a lot of time (~6 minutes) to boot up. When I shutdown using  "Alt+F4 -> Shut down", it boots up very fast.

I have fast startup turned on. I started noticing this only after I dual-booted with Linux Mint.

What is the reason behind the slow boot time when shutting down via "Start menu -> Shut down"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked about **(1) the reason for a slow boot time when shutting down via Start menu -> Shut down**.

That is expected behaviour when you have Fast Startup enabled, and it was covered by harrymc.
You can easily confirm that this is the reason for a slow boot by [disabling Fast Startup](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html) and checking. You can also try [Restart instead of Shutdown+Startup](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/what-is-the-difference-between-restart-and-shut/d512fa31-3bce-49bc-bada-11eda28e3b7f) (see also [this](https://computer.howstuffworks.com/restarting-shutting-down-computer.htm#:%7E:text=In%20older%20versions%20of%20Windows,your%20PC%20up%20and%20running.), among the many sources available), that should produce a faster startup.
A further reason for a slow boot is when updates are applied, but I assume you are not referring to that case.

I understand you are especially concerned about **(2) why this would only start happening after setting up a dual boot with Linux Mint**. That is actually strange, since what you found is also expected without dual boot.
The only explanation I find is:

1. Somehow you enabled Fast Startup at about the same time you set up dual boot.
2. You started having more applications that restart upon boot at about the same time you set up dual boot.

You could make a few tests (e.g., with/without Fast Startup, using Shutdown/Reboot).
This will of course not answer question 2, but it helps with question 1.

Note that it is often recommended disabling Fast Startup when dual booting, as it may have issues when mounting the Windows partition in Linux, e.g.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/828394/do-i-need-to-disable-windows-fast-startup-if-ubuntu-is-installed-on-a-separate-d

---

This information is complementary to the answer by harrymc, as it refers to the same possible cause of slow restarting.

[This](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7418-shut-down-computer-windows-10-a.html) shows various forms for shutting down, including hybrid shutdown (fast startup) or full shutdown.

[This](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/96619-add-shut-down-context-menu-windows-10-a.html) shows how to add a context menu that helps selecting the method for shutting down.

[image]

Related:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_perf-insiderplat_pc/programs-autostart-after-boot-in-windows-10/09dd8d3e-7b36-45d1-9181-6587dd5d53ab?auth=1

Answer (score 2):

It's a weird thing, in newer windows 10 builds every shutdown method (Alt+F4, shutdown.exe) should take same time.

However if you have Automatic updates turned on, and after you reboot, then windows will configure updates. This was true for only Start menu > Shutdown **before**. I can remember it was easily possible in windows 7.

There were two known ways of bypassing update configurations:

- Hit Alt+F4 and shutdown from there.
- Run `shutdown -s -t 0` command from Cmd.
- Cut power supply (**Highly Dangerous**)

**But, the loopholes are now closed.**

The posibilites are of the fast shutdown from alt+f4:

- You are using an old build of Windows 10
- You are using an older version of Windows

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference between shutdown from the Start menu and the older method of
<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd>
is that the later method will disable the newer option of running restartable
applications on the next boot. It will also not execute any pending Windows Update
operations.

Automatically restarting currently running application on boot could cause
performance issues on some hardware. Opening a multitude of apps simultaneously
can in this case cause significant resource contention, leaving you waiting longer
to get operational.

References:

- [Applications Not Reopening After Restart](https://superuser.com/questions/1445763/applications-not-reopening-after-restart)
- [How to Turn On or Off Use sign-in info to auto finish setting up device after update or restart in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/49963-use-sign-info-auto-finish-after-update-restart-windows-10-a.html)
- [How to stop Windows 10 restarting your apps after you login](https://www.onmsft.com/how-to/how-to-stop-windows-10-restarting-your-apps-after-you-login)

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a way to bypass pending updates using Alt-F4 and shutdown in Windows 7.  Perhaps this same method works in Win 10 even though it does not tell you that's what it's doing.

I believe this is not the case in Win 10 (unless you're using an early build... say around 2016/17?).  Can you confirm your build number? (winver.exe in run dialog)